# G+ signin on android throws INVALID_CLIENT_ID

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-play-services

I am trying to implement G+ sign in, in our app, however, despite having repeatedly updating the client id, and recreating a new one as well, I keep on getting an error saying

```
I/GLSUser﹕ GLS error: INVALID_CLIENT_ID myemail@domain.com oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

Not sure what's wrong. I can see the account list popup, and everything else seems to work as well. I have double checked my client id as well.

[EDIT]

Here is the code I am using

```
    private void getGoogleAccessToken() {
        Bundle appActivities = new Bundle();
        appActivities.putString(GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_VISIBLE_ACTIVITIES, "AddActivity BuyActivity");
        String scopes = "oauth2:server:client_id:number-randomness.apps.googleusercontent.com" + ":api_scope:"+ Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN;
        mGoogleToken = null;

        try {
            mGoogleToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this, mPlusClient.getAccountName(), scopes, appActivities);
        } catch (IOException transientEx) {
            // network or server error, the call is expected to succeed if you try again later.
            // Don't attempt to call again immediately - the request is likely to
            // fail, you'll hit quotas or back-off.
            Crouton.makeText(this, R.string.google_bad_boy, Style.ALERT).show();
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            // Recover
            Crouton.makeText(this, R.string.google_bad_boy, Style.ALERT).show();
        } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
            // Failure. The call is not expected to ever succeed so it should not be
            // retried.
            Crouton.makeText(this, R.string.google_not_allow_login, Style.ALERT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Crouton.makeText(this, R.string.google_not_allow_login, Style.ALERT).show();
//          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

[EDIT 2]

Seemingly I an getting a not successful result for Activity in this code:

```
    mGoogleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
                    mConnectionProgressDialog.show();
                    if (mConnectionResult != null) {
                        try {
                            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(SplashActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Try connecting again.
                            mPlusClient.connect();
                        }
                    } else {
                        mPlusClient.connect();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you've updated your details on the Consent Screen in your project settings in the Google Developer console. You need to confirm your (developer) email address, and provide a name for your app which will be displayed to the user in the permissions confirmation screen.

While the Google+ QuickStart guide (https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android) doesn't talk about this explicitly, you need to do this (very simple), else you'll get an INVALID_CLIENT_ID error on your device.

Comment: This post has helped me a lot, too bad it is not accepted as it should be!

Comment: So, so dumb, Google.  All I needed to do was add the product name that I already had defined and set the only email address on the account...

Comment: Where would we be with out Stack Overflow?

Comment: Also, don't forget to give it 10-15 minutes or so to let the changes actully take effect.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause is the package name or the SHA1 key in the API console not matching the one in the application. Make sure you're using the same keystore as you extracted the SHA1 from for the client ID, and check there are no spaces in the package name or key (including at the beginning or end).

Edit: based on the code, your scopes are wrong. You're missing the https://www.googleapis.com/auth from the start. The only scopes which are "bare" are spec ones Luke "profile" and "email". Similarly, app activity types requested in the bundle are URL-formatted, so you need to make sure you are using the https://...

With cards to the activity result, make sure you call getToken again. The flow with Google Auth Util is effectively separate from the PlusClient flow. You can think of one as for the client side, one as for the server. If the resolution was started from the getToken exception, you need to call to getToken again. If it was started from resolving a ConnectionResult from PlusClient, you need to PlusClient.connect again. So your onClick code there is likely no related to your getToken setup. In general, make sure you harmonise the scopes and app activities being requested across the two - there's a break down of a client and server flow for Android here: http://www.riskcompletefailure.com/2013/10/google-android-client-server-sign-in.html

Comment: Tried, and tested them all, still the same result. This is the client id right? `some_number-random_string.apps.googleusercontent.com`

Comment: Thats right, though you shouldnt need to us that anywhere in the app itself as it is looked up automatically. The client it should look somewhat like the one in step f of https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_1_enable_the_google_api

Comment: Ian, I want to get a server side token, so that I can get a long access token to store on the server. For the same I am following the section `Server-side access for your app`

Comment: Ah i see - you will need both an android client id and a server one in that case - the code is generated against the server id but the consent happens against the client if that makes sense.

Comment: Yep, Exactly what I am trying. I created an server app as well, but that doesn't seem to be helping either.

Comment: Can you update the question with the code youre using for the call to getToken, it may be an issue with the string you are creating there.

Comment: Which part of it? Api scopes?

Comment: Yep. Plus.login should be https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login (including https://www. - SO seems to be hiding that) - same with the rest. You could drop userinfo.profile as it doesnt give you anything extra incidentally.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Lastly the client id should be android client id? or service account client id?

Comment: The one in that string should be the server client id, which should be a web type one, not service account. Note that when exchanging the code on the server you should not pass a redirect_uri.

Comment: Used a web type client id. Still the same result. Any ways I can test this in a sample app?

Comment: Ah noticed same problem with app activity types - they are URL structured as well. If that doesnt work can you log out the final scope string check it looks as expected.

Comment: It seems, the error occurs right at trying to do mPlusClient.connect.